# How to read an element from a txt file list (python)

Tags: python, indexing

as the topic says, I need help with my python code.
When I enter ID with 1, it prints a result of

```
"Error 
None"
```

I  guess that the None comes from the print(grp). Btw, I am not familiar with the (with..as...) kind of coding. I only know the [file=open('...','r')] kind.. New to python here

```
def hihi(ID):
  file=open('a.txt','r')
  iden=ID
  try:
        for line in file.readlines():
           line1=line.split('\t')
           if line1[1]==1:
               if (line1[0]==iden):
               grp=line1[3]
    file.close()
    return grp
    except:
        print('Error')
        return
ID=int(input('Enter ID'))
grp=hihi(ID)
print(grp)
```

The 'a.txt' file are recorded as follow:

1 \t a \t 11 \t ATO \t 2 \t y \t 000 \t aaa

Comment: What is the *specific* problem with your code?

Comment: Do `except Exception as e:print(e)` don't hide the stacktrace, the answer is in there

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll first fix the identation. I added with...as.. so you don't have to close the file in the end.

```
def hihi(ID):
  with open('a.txt','r') as file:
    # Removed 'iden=ID' because you can just use 'ID'

    try:
      for line in file.readlines():
        line1 = line.split('\t')

        if line1[1] is '1 ': # The first item in 'line1' is '1 ' (note the extra space)
          if line1[0] is str(ID): # 'line1[0]' returns the first char, which is '1', I casted the ID to a string to compare them
            grp = line1[3] # 'line1' is a list of only 2 items, so only 'line1[0]' and 'line1[1]' return something

      return grp

    except Exception as e:
      print(e) # Print the stacktrace
      return

ID = int(input('Enter ID'))
grp = hihi(ID)
print(grp)
# grp didn't receive a value because 'hihi' causes an error and returns 'None' instead of a value
```

First print your stacktrace to see why the line reader causes an error